# Shiny reactive dataset within observeEvent

Tags: r, events, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have a very simple app which fails. The reason it fails is that the reactive dataset is available solely within the observeEvent function but not outside. I use observeEvent to get datasets from two different sources wrangled. For this example I simply used cbind. My actual code is much more complicated.

This is a logical / syntax related problem but all my searching came up short. In essence I want merged_data() to be available for all parts of the app.

Minimum repr example - this **fails** because merged_data() is not available outside of the ObserveEvent.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("testing 1 2 3"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
      ),


      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
         fluidRow(
            column(width = 2,
                   offset = 0,
                   align = "center",
                   actionButton(inputId = "fetch_data_inputId",
                                label = "data")

            ) #column
            ,
            column(width = 10,
                   offset = 0,
                   align = "center",
                   DT::dataTableOutput("DT1")
            ) #column

         )#fluidrow
      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output,session) {

   observeEvent(input$fetch_data_inputId, {

      req(iris) 

      button_data <- colnames(iris)

      merged_data <- reactive({

         if( !is.null(cbind(iris[,1:4],iris3))) {
            cbind(iris[,1:4],iris3)
         } else {NULL}
      })


   }) #observeevent

   output$DT1 <- renderDataTable({#

      rendered_table <- merged_data()

      DT::datatable(rendered_table)
   })   


}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Minimum repr example - this **works** because the datatable is created within the ObserveEvent.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("testing 1 2 3"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
      ),


      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
         fluidRow(
            column(width = 2,
                   offset = 0,
                   align = "center",
                   actionButton(inputId = "fetch_data_inputId",
                                label = "data")

            ) #column
            ,
            column(width = 10,
                   offset = 0,
                   align = "center",
                   DT::dataTableOutput("DT1")
            ) #column

         )#fluidrow
      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output,session) {

   observeEvent(input$fetch_data_inputId, {

      req(iris) 

      button_data <- colnames(iris)

      merged_data <- reactive({

         if( !is.null(cbind(iris[,1:4],iris3))) {
            cbind(iris[,1:4],iris3)
         } else {NULL}
      })


      output$DT1 <- renderDataTable({#

         rendered_table <- merged_data()

         DT::datatable(rendered_table)
      })   

   }) #observeevent



}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

What I really need is for the reactive dataset to continue being created within observeEvent but to be accessible outside of the ObserveEvent environment so that i use it in other parts of the app, but I suspect it's the wrong approach. So anything that works would be great.

Comment: Try using `reactiveValue` instead of `reactive`.

Comment: You can do `merged_data <- eventReactive(input$fetch_data_inputId, {......` and like this you don't need `observeEvent`.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. If I sub reactive for reactiveValue the first piece of code continues to error out.  Subbing observeEvent with eventReactive also continues to error out .  In both cases the error is "Warning: Error in merged_data: could not find function "merged_data"

Comment: If you defined `merged_data <- eventReactive(input$fetch_data_inputId, {......` there's no reason that this function is not found. You did a mistake somewhere. Did you remove the `observeEvent`?

Comment: Stephane, you are right. I subbed the observeEvent with eventReactive whereas you did not suggest this. It's working now - you should put it down as the answer.

Comment: Is the additional variable assignment being done for any purpose? Only 'output$DT1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
      merged_data()
   })' should do it.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent   Could I ask, what if I wanted to declare two merged_data objects - each used for different purposes. Should I keep using eventReactive and convert to list?

Comment: @Sagar Agreed. Only because "rendered_table" is general and I use it to pass customised formats for multiple datatables.

Comment: I have a similar question if anyone wants to take a stab at it. Really stuck here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55329078/text-input-with-action-button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("testing 1 2 3"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
      ),


      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
         fluidRow(
            column(width = 2,
                   offset = 0,
                   align = "center",
                   actionButton(inputId = "fetch_data_inputId",
                                label = "data")

            ) #column
            ,
            column(width = 10,
                   offset = 0,
                   align = "center",
                   DT::dataTableOutput("DT1")
            ) #column

         )#fluidrow
      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output,session) {

   merged_data <- eventReactive(input$fetch_data_inputId, {
      req(iris) 

      button_data <- colnames(iris)

      if( !is.null(cbind(iris[,1:4],iris3))) {
         cbind(iris[,1:4],iris3)
      } else {NULL}

   }) #eventReactive

   output$DT1 <- renderDataTable({#
      rendered_table <- merged_data()
      DT::datatable(rendered_table)
   })   
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```